# 3rd order ODE: System of Linear Eq. from a initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, initial-value-problems

The given equation and initial values are 
$$y^{'''}+12y^{''}+36y^{'}=0$$
$$y(0)=0$$
$$y'(0)=1$$
$$y''(0)=-7$$
Using the auxiliary equation and factor we get
$$m_1=0, \space m_{2,3}=-6$$ 
Then the equation becomes 
$$y= c_1+c_2e^{-6x}+c_3xe^{-6x}$$
Now taking the derivatives and substituting in the IVTs
$$0=c_1+c_2$$
$$1=-6c_2+c_3$$
$$-7=36c_2-12c_3$$

Now here is where I am stuck, what are the steps in finding the values for $c_1, c_2,c_3$. I tried adding them all together but that was fruitless. I then tried to solve each equation independently in terms of each other but could find a proper fit.

Comment: Solve the last two equations alone as a system of two equations...Find $c_2,c_3$ then deduce $c_1=-c_2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $$1=-6c_2+c_3\\ -7=36c_2-12c_3$$
we have
$$6=-36c_2+6c_3\\-7=36c_2-12c_3$$
adding:
$$-1=-6c_3\implies c_3=\frac{1}{6}.$$
Now from $1=-6c_2+c_3$, we have
$$1=-6c_2+\frac{1}{6}\implies c_2=-\frac{5}{36} $$
and from $0=c_1+c_2$, we have $$c_1=-c_2=\frac{5}{36}.$$